# What will be the spring bean creation flow for nested @component annotations

Tags: spring

```
@Component
public classA {

  @Component
  public static classB {
  }

  @Component
  public static classC {
  }

}
```

what will be the order for spring bean creation here?

Comment: But, my code is running perfectly using nested component annotations.

Comment: Ok, apologizes. I take that back. I was testing it but I made a different mistake. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When scanning classes Spring will check for dependencies to determine creation order. `ClassB` and `ClassC` will get created before `ClassA` but which of the other two classes will get created first is unspecified, unless one of them also has a dependency on the other.